# Count and Max with Datatable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

For a house project, I'm using [Datatable](http://datatables.net)  because it is very user friendly. This example is a clean code which I work.

I extract 2 columns from my database : "login" and "date_visit" .

```
$table = 'name_table';
$primaryKey = 'id_table';
$columns = array(

    array(
        'db' => '`table`.`login`',
        'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'login',
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return $d;
            }
    ),

    array(
        'db' => '`table`.`date_visit`',
        'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'date_visit',
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fra');
            if (date('Y', $d) != date('Y', time())) {
                return ucwords(utf8_encode(strftime ("%A %d %B %Y &agrave; %H:%M" , $d)));
            } else {
                return ucwords(utf8_encode(strftime ("%A %d %B &agrave; %H:%M" , $d)));
            }
         }
    )
);

$sql_details = $mysqli->arrayMysqli();

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/ssp.class.php');

$joinQuery = 'FROM `'.$table.'`';
$extraWhere = '`table`.`login` = '.$function->getLogin();

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery, $extraWhere )
);
```

I spent the last 2 evenings to look how to retrieve the number of times the user has logged on. So I try to make a "`SELECT COUNT (date_visit) ...`", but I have not found how to proceed with Datatable.

Also, I would like to understand how is it possible to recover via Datatable the date of the last visit. Same problem here, I did not understand how to make a "`SELECT MAX (date_visit) ...`"

Comment: What is you db structure? How are the tables related? do you have a login table with a field login and a date_visit with a date_visit field? What happens when you login, both a date_visit record and a login record are inserted?

Comment: Table (id_table, login, date_visit) . That´s all

Comment: so what does login hold? the number of logins or if he is logged in or not?

Comment: This is not the subject of my question. What I wonder is totally independent of that. However, the login contains the number of login_id

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, the SQL you are looking for is The SQL should be 'SELECT login_id, COUNT (date_visit) as times_visited, max(date_visit) as last_visit FROM Table GROUP BY login_id', but I believe you are looking for the SSP code to allow you to get to it right?

Comment: Exactly ! ... I know how to do this without ssp class, but I need to use it, in the aim of user friendly. Have you an idea about this ? :)

Comment: According to this https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php i do not see a way to put in a Groupby. Just create a normal query and json_encode the results. Or extend the SSP class and add a way to put in Group By.

Comment: I am not sure how your code would work as SSP::simple has 5 parameters and you have 7. Are you using some other SSP class then the one I linked?

Comment: I'm learning about json and i'm not an expert. Do you know how to do this. I explain. I know how to json a query, but i don't know how to integrate it into the json which come from the ssp class. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65788/discussion-between-mihai-p-and-zlen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell us in advance that you are not using the normal SSP class but an extension of it probably this one: https://github.com/emran/ssp/blob/master/ssp.php
The one that you use has a column $groupBy = '' use that one to group things.

Comment: i opened a chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65788/discussion-between-mihai-p-and-zlen